# How to get all possible transitions from a state in xstate

Tags: xstate

Given an xState fsm like the [counter](https://xstate.js.org/docs/examples/counter.html#modeling-min-and-max) or [search](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/guards.html#guard-functions) example.

How is it possible to enumerate the possible transitions? I tried

```js
const current = service.state
const stateNode = service.machine
const isActive = !stateNode.parent || current.matches(stateNode.path.join('.')) || undefined
getEdges(<where do I get this node?>, { depth: 0 }).reduce((actions, edge)
```

The problem is I do not know what to hand in to `getEdges` as first argument. When the fsm has just started, handing in `stateNode` does not yield any edges. However, the xState VIZ app clearly shows the active state has transitions.

Answer (score 1):

I've played around with parts of `@xstate/graph` and this example is as close as I get to what you want:

```
import { Machine } from "xstate"

import { getShortestPaths } from '@xstate/graph'

export const feedbackMachine = Machine({
    id: 'feedback',
    initial: 'question',
    states: {
        question: {
            on: {
                CLICK_GOOD: 'thanks',
                CLICK_BAD: 'form',
                CLOSE: 'closed',
                ESC: 'closed',
                REMOVE_ME: 'nope'
            }
        },
        form: {
            on: {
                SUBMIT: 'thanks',
                CLOSE: 'closed',
                ESC: 'closed'
            }
        },
        nope: {
            on: {

            }
        },
        thanks: {
            on: {
                CLOSE: 'closed',
                ESC: 'closed'
            }
        },
        closed: {
            type: 'final'
        }
    }
})

const showPaths = () => {
    const paths = getShortestPaths(feedbackMachine)
    const states = Object.keys(paths).filter(k => paths[k].weight > 0)
    console.log(states)
    // [""thanks"", ""form"", ""closed"", ""nope""]
}

showPaths()
```

Once you remove `REMOVE_ME: 'nope'` from the possible transitions in the question state, you should see the result as: `[""thanks"", ""form"", ""closed""]` in `showPaths`

I also see getEdges have been removed recently from `@xstate/graph` so I'd steer away from using it for now.